# Looking to migrate away from AWS Amplify, what are the best alternatives for Appsync and Datastore?

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-amplify

I've been banging my head against the lack of active answers to my questions for a month now, and I'm considering migrating my early-stage app away from amplify before getting any deeper. There's a few components/features I'm trying to resolve to make it easier to walk away. Maybe someone can point me to something effective?

I'm currently using Amplify in a React app with a node back-end, so those languages/environments would be ideal.

An efficient way to map graphl to dynamodb and vice-versa. I basically am looking for a low-effort way to translate all my query routes and (optional) subscription routes. I'd sorta prefer if this solution were more code and less (no?) vtl, but I'll take a balance. I have semi-complex auth rules and I'm happy to manage them manually.

A replacement for DataStore that will let me treat things as persistent objects. Frankly, I like this pattern a lot but DataStore doesn't seem to let me write the code that feeds its persistence layer.

That's... about it. I can handle cognito by hand. I can handle authentication by hand.

Any thoughts/directions/library ideas? Preferably something mature after I was so bit by amplify.

Comment: Each tool has it's pros and cons, I can suggest https://firebase.google.com/ which has Firestore as a replacement for AWS Datastore, Realtime database, File Storage, Cloud Messaging for push notification, Analytics, A/B Testing, Functions (allow run functions that implement business logic), and other tools that may be interesting.